# flutter iOS Capabilities Background Modes was on

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm using FCM for my app and I'm sure I never toggled on the Background Modes but I just noticed that remote notification was on.
I have no idea how this was toggled.
Push Notifications is on do I need to keep Background Modes on?

Comment: You can disable it if you want. This mode enables your app that is in background to intercept the notification arrival and through a delegate method fetch some new content from the net.

Comment: Look at the official documentation **Using Push Notifications to Initiate a Download** https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Thank you guys for comment! I don't have any background execution so I guess I can disable it. Does this affect push notifications or it has nothing to do with push notifications?

Comment: It affects only in this way. If disabled, If your app is in background the method `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is not called until the user tap on the notification. Instead, if you enable it if the app is in the background this method is called automatically by the system. Pay attention that if the user as swiped-closed your app you fall back in the user tap scenario.

Comment: Ok I understood. Thank you for your clear explanation!

Comment: You're welcome. And remember. The best way to master it is giving it a try! And also remember that Android and iOS systems differ a lot in how they natively handle remote notifications, when your app is closed or in background state.

Comment: Yeah I'll keep that in mind! I'll be careful about that thanks so much for your help.